# How to disable the intent in Dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es

I have created an intent in dialogflow and want to disable it. I don't want to delete it because I may use it in future.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

I didn't find an option to delete it at the time of writing the answer.

You can only set priority to it Highest, High, Normal, Low & Ignore

You need to choose Ignore to consider it as delete.

[image: Ignore the Dialogflow intent]